# Problem 3-38 in Spivak´s Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, integration, manifolds, differential-topology

This is not homework. Problem 3-38 reads:

*Let $A_{n}$ be a closed set contained in $(n,n+1)$. Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\int_{A_{n}}f=(-1)^{n}/n$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\notin$ any $A_{n}$. Find two partitions of unity $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ such that $\sum_{\phi\in\Phi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi\cdot f$ and $\sum_{\psi\in\Psi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi\cdot f$ converge absolutely to different values.*

**A few observations:** First, $n\ge 1$. Second, Spivak uses what he calls an *extended integral*, whose definition and relations with the usual integral can be found on p.65, which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244283/do-we-need-additional-assumptions-for-problem-3-37-b-in-spivaks-calculus-on-m/244453#244453) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173237/is-this-definition-missing-some-assumptions).

It may be helpful to have an example of such a function in mind. Let $A_{n}=$ closed interval of length $1/2n$ centered at the point $(2n+1)/2$. Clearly $A_{n}\subset(n,n+1)$. then define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
        \hphantom{-}2& \text{if $x\in A_{n}$ for $n$ even}\\
        -2& \text{if $x\in A_{n}$ for $n$ odd}\\
        \hphantom{-}0& \text{otherwise}.
       \end{cases}$$

**A possible approach:** Let $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}/n$. Since $\sum_{n}a_{n}=\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ but the convergence is conditional, then for any $\beta\not=\alpha$ there is a [rearrangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) $\{b_{n}\}$ of the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such that $\sum_{n}b_{n}=\beta$.

Now, we form a family of open sets $\{U_{n}\}$, where $U_{n}$ is the union of $n$ intervals $(k,k+1)$, each corresponding to a term of the $n$-th partial sum of $\sum_{n}a_{n}$. We form a similar family $\{V_{n}\}$ looking at the partial sums of $\sum_{n}b_{n}$. E.g., if we let $\{b_{n}\}=\{-1,1/2,1/4,-1/3,1/6,1/8,-1/5,\ldots\}$ we have $V_{3}=(1,2)\cup(2,3)\cup(4,5)$ while since $\{a_{n}\}=\{-1,1/2,-1/3,1/4,\ldots\}$ we have $U_{3}=(1,2)\cup(2,3)\cup(3,4)$.

If we slightly *fatten-up* the $U_{n}$ (resp. the $V_{n}$) we form open covers $\mathcal{U}$ (resp. $\mathcal{V}$) of all the reals greater or equal than 1 without ading points where $f$ in non-zero. My heart tells me that partitions of unity $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ subordinate to $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$, respectively, will be the desired one. But alas I am lost!

**Does any one know how to show that the aforementioned partitions of unity are the desired ones?**

**Other possible approaches to the solution are also welcomed.**

In addition to two posts linked above, related issues with other problems and statements about integration in Spivak´s book can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127616/an-application-of-partitions-of-unity-integrating-over-open-sets/243671#243671) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239965/solving-problem-3-29-in-spivaks-calculus-on-manifolds-without-using-change-of-v).

Answer (score 4):

Since Spivak requires absolute convergence, it is not enough to rearrange the series. We need a "blocking" lemma of the following kind:

**Lemma.** Suppose $\sum a_n$ is a conditionally convergent series. Then for every $\beta\in \mathbb R$ there exists a partition $\mathbb N=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty B_j$ where each set $B_j$ is finite, and the series $\sum_j \left(\sum_{n\in B_j} a_n\right)$ converges absolutely to $\beta$.

Assume the lemma for now. Our partition should include open sets $U_j=\bigcup_{n\in B_j}(j,j+1)$. These do not cover the integers, though. Cover each integer by a tiny interval $(n-\epsilon,n+\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is small enough so that the interval does not meet the sets $A_n$ and $A_{n-1}$. Note that $f$ is identically zero within such intervals. For each $n$, the set $A_n$ meets exactly one element $U_j$ of our open cover; therefore, the corresponding function $\varphi_j$ from a partition of unity will be identically $1$ on $A_n$. We have $\int f\varphi_j=\sum_{n\in B_j} a_n$ which gives the desired result. $\quad\Box$

As for the lemma, the proof goes like this: first, rearrange the series so that it converges conditionally to $\beta$; then divide the rearranged series $\sum a_{\sigma(k)}$ into blocks $N_i\le \sigma(k)<N_{i+1}$, $i=1,2,3,\dots$ such that the sum within the $i$th block is at most $2^{-i}$ for all $i\ge 2$. (Idea: cut off the tail repeatedly when it gets smaller than $2^{-i}$.)

Comment: I disagree with the sentence "the corresponding function $\varphi_j$ from a partition of unity will be identically $1$ on $A_n$." I think we need to take the (finite) sum of all the $\varphi_\alpha$ that is not identically zero on the compact set $\bigcup_{n\in B_j} A_n$ (i.e., merge all these functions into one function) and consider this modified partition of unity as the desired one.